# Looping through objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm looping trough 2-dimensional objects inside an array. I currently do this the following way:

My array looks like this

```
var myarray = [
    0: {
          child_obj: {}
       }
    1: {//etc}
];
```

And I loop through the second-level objects like this

```
jQuery.each(myarray, function(i, first) {
    jQuery.each(first.child_obj, function(j, second) {
        //do stuff
     }
    });
});
```

So that's a loop inside a loop. It works fine, but it doesn't look very neat and I feel there might be a better (and shorter) way to do this.
The reason I'm doing this is because I need to do stuff with all `child_obj`s.

Worth mentioning:

- I use `jQuery.each()` because this allows looping through objects, while `for()`, `.map()` etc. can't handle that properly.
- I can't change the structure of the array or its contents
- I don't need to use the indexes (args `i` and `j`).

Is there a better way?

Comment: Array.prototype.forEach()

Comment: @user7951676 Could you explain how I should use this to get through the second-level objects?

Comment: @JaromandaX What do you mean?

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess you meant `var myarray = []`.. I edited the question :)

Comment: what @user7951676 is trying to say is, that using array forEach for the array is "neater" than jquery each for the array - for the object, you can use jquery each, or Object.keys/Object.values/Object.entries instead if you want to remove all use of jquery

Comment: SomeArray.forEach(function(obj){})

Comment: Than iterate with a for in loop over obj in the callback

Comment: The array literal in the OP has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ditch jquery (and it's slow speed in .each) and use ES2015+

```js
var myarray = [
    {
        child_obj: {a:1,b:2,c:3}
    },
    {
        child_obj: {a:4,b:5,c:6},
        child_obj2: {a:7,b:8,c:9}
    }
];
// specific rewrite of your code would be
myarray.forEach(obj => Object.values(obj.child_obj).forEach(value => {
    console.log(value);
}));

console.log('-------');
// other examples
myarray.forEach(obj => Object.values(obj).forEach(value => {
    // do things with each "child object"
    console.log(value);
}));

myarray.forEach(obj => Object.values(obj).forEach(child => Object.values(child).forEach(value => {
    // do things with each property in each child object
    console.log(value);
})));
```

Comment: Not bad, although I'm not sure if this does the right thing for me. Each object has some attributes of which `child_obj` is just one (maybe should've mentioned that), and it logs for each attribute it loops through. Moreover, if one of these 1st-level attributes have null or undefined value, the loop breaks..

Answer (score 0):

It's not a better way, it's more like alternate.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
{
  var child_obj = myarray[i].child_obj;
  // get the keys of this object
  var keys = Object.keys(child_obj);

  // loop all those keys
  for (var keyi = 0; keyi < keys.length; keyi++)
  {
    var key  = keys[keyi];
    // get the objects item based on key;
    var item = child_obj[key];
  }
}
```

but here you can change their values directly as you are iterating the original vars.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

using underscore-js library, you can do the following:

```
var first = _.map(myarray, element => { return element.child_obj; });
_.each(first, element => {/*do stuff*/});
```

Comment: This doesn't loop through the child objects; if I do something with `first.child_obj` in the top-level loop, in my jQuery.each, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use forEach with a for in loop inside::

```
myArray.forEach(function(obj){
for(var i in obj){
// do stuff
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive recursive approach can be used for primitive types:

```js
function forEachPrimitive(o, f, k) { if (o !== Object(o)) f(k, o)
                                     else for (k in o) forEachPrimitive(o[k], f, k) }

var obj = [ { x: { a: '0', b: true, c: 2         } },
            { y: { d: /3/, e: null, f: undefined } } ]

forEachPrimitive(obj, console.log)
```